# How to escape the less than symbol for SQL insertion in DataMapper

Tags: sql, datamapper

I'm trying to insert a value with a `<` symbol in it, but each time, it just cuts off the remainder of the string:

```
winecheap = Tag.first_or_create(:tag_type => tt, :value => "Wine & Spirits <$65")

  DEBUG -  (0.000828) SELECT "uuid", "created_at", "updated_at", "value", "es_indexed", "tag_type_uuid" FROM "tags" WHERE ("tag_type_uuid" = 'a932f2c1-e8bb-44cc-9120-791097474b77' AND "value" = 'Wine & Spirits <$65') ORDER BY "uuid" LIMIT 1
  DEBUG -  (0.001027) INSERT INTO "tags" ("created_at", "updated_at", "uuid", "value", "es_indexed", "tag_type_uuid") VALUES ('2013-07-29T20:03:32+00:00', '2013-07-29T20:03:32+00:00', '76a5b023-41b6-4e6b-9f2b-e9fbe51ee1b0', 'Wine & Spirits ', FALSE, 'a932f2c1-e8bb-44cc-9120-791097474b77')
 => #<Tag @created_at=Mon, 29 Jul 2013 20:03:32 +0000 @updated_at=Mon, 29 Jul 2013 20:03:32 +0000 @uuid=#<UUID:0x3fdb200f4e6c UUID:76a5b023-41b6-4e6b-9f2b-e9fbe51ee1b0> @value="Wine & Spirits " @es_indexed=false @tag_type_uuid=#<UUID:0x3fdb1f2b8290 UUID:a932f2c1-e8bb-44cc-9120-791097474b77>>
1.9.3-p286 :079 
> winecheap.value
 => "Wine & Spirits "
```

What's the way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked OK.

```
repository(:default).adapter.execute('UPDATE "tags" SET "value"=\'Wine & Spirits <$65\' WHERE "uuid" = \'0cfa3a0c-adfb-4b67-92af-a7ee46d9289c\'')
```